# getting positional argument error by using folium module

Tags: python, geopandas, folium

I have a dataset of covid 19 total death, cases, and country names I want to add all details in the map using the folium model but I'm stuck

```
 ## General Libraries for data analysis
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#for visulization
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import folium
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
# read dataset
data = pd.read_csv("covid_data.csv")
data.head()
# maiking map
m = folium.Map(location=[20,0], tiles="OpenStreetMap", zoom_start=2)
for i in range(0,len(data)): 
   folium.Marker(
       location=[data.iloc[i]['Latitude'], data.iloc[i]['Longitude']],
       popup=data.iloc[i]['Total_Case'], +' ' + data.iloc[i]['Total_Death'], +' ' + data.iloc[i][ 'Country'],
    ).add_to(m)
# # Show the map again
m
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Users\darshan\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2388/391102649.py", line 16
    ).add_to(m)
    ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

In map by using popup I want to display all total death total cases and name of country.

Comment: There are strange commas on the line before it. Voting to close as typo. (For instance, one of your arguments is `+' ' + data.iloc[i]['Total_Death']`.)

Answer (score 0):

- you did not provide reference to your data, so I constructed some sample data of same format as your data frame
- the error I received from your code was different

  - invalid syntax for concatenation of floats into a string
  - replaced with an f-string

#### solution

```
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    folium.Marker(
        location=[data.iloc[i]["Latitude"], data.iloc[i]["Longitude"]],
        popup=f'{data.iloc[i]["Total_Case"]} {data.iloc[i]["Total_Death"]} {data.iloc[i]["Country"]}',
    ).add_to(m)
```

#### full code as MWE with data

```
## General Libraries for data analysis
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

# for visulization
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import folium
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

# read dataset
# data = pd.read_csv("covid_data.csv")
data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Latitude,Longitude,name,Country,Total_Death,Total_Case
33.8739209756269,35.507762351377664,Beirut,Lebanon,10365.0,1095811.0
8.969963049094872,-79.53498301041077,Panama City,Panama,8179.0,769457.0
-3.376087220374643,29.360006061528395,Bujumbura,Burundi,38.0,38812.0
0.3853886097185182,9.457965045823698,Libreville,Gabon,303.0,47594.0
-22.570006084383806,17.08354610054181,Windhoek,Namibia,4022.0,158112.0
5.551980464445933,-0.21866159896069348,Accra,Ghana,1445.0,161114.0
27.472985859175765,89.63901403703,Thimphu,Bhutan,19.0,54592.0
-12.04606681752557,-77.05200795343472,Lima,Peru,212676.0,3557139.0
19.444388301415472,-99.1329340602939,Mexico City,Mexico,323973.0,5729270.0
-6.172471846798885,106.82749176247012,Jakarta,Indonesia,155937.0,6041269.0
18.086427021247516,-15.975340414890013,Nouakchott,Mauritania,982.0,58683.0
14.103990759076396,-87.2194751979415,Tegucigalpa,Honduras,10892.0,422239.0
0.318604813383331,32.581377667121046,Kampala,Uganda,3597.0,164058.0
-8.559388408546454,125.57945593170507,Dili,Timor-Leste,130.0,22853.0
4.366644306349087,18.558288125287277,Bangui,Central African Rep.,113.0,14649.0
17.96669272762739,102.59998002015476,Vientiane,Laos,727.0,201460.0
31.778407815573303,35.20662593459866,Jerusalem,Palestine,5657.0,656876.0
38.901495235087054,-77.01136443943716,"Washington, D.C.",United States of America,989331.0,80732932.0
-16.49602775504337,-68.15193104910219,La Paz,Bolivia,21904.0,904029.0"""))

data.head()
# maiking map
m = folium.Map(location=[20, 0], tiles="OpenStreetMap", zoom_start=2)
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    folium.Marker(
        location=[data.iloc[i]["Latitude"], data.iloc[i]["Longitude"]],
        popup=f'{data.iloc[i]["Total_Case"]} {data.iloc[i]["Total_Death"]} {data.iloc[i]["Country"]}',
    ).add_to(m)
# Show the map again
m
```

#### sample output

[image]